# Why can I not move lines in my Livecode DataGrid anymore?

Tags: livecode

I have a stack that has been running quite well. I then changed it to have a launcher stack which calls the main application stack which is now password protected. I am running on Livecode 6.7 and use Datagrid Helper as well. All of a sudden, my datagrid does not act the way it did before - when I select a line, I can no longer move it up or down within the datagrid as I could do before.

Comment: This is caused by Livecode 6.7 so remain on the latest stable version of Livecode (6.6.2) until 6.7 becomes a formal production release of Livecode.

Comment: Hi Danny, could you send us a sample of what you are seeing at quality.runrev.com. We're working on the next version of LiveCode 6.7 at the moment and we'd really like to resolve that issue if we can.